# Нужно сортировать товар по цене и по бренду yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Как сделать сортировку по цене, `price` и как сделать фильтр по бренду

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => Shop::find()->where(['status'=>1, 'men' => 1])->orderBy('id DESC'),
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 20,
            ],
        ]);
```

Comment: а разве в `orderBy` нельзя передать массив?

Answer (score 0):

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => Shop::find()->where(['status'=>1, 'men' => 1])
            ->orderBy([
               'id' => SORT_DESC,
               'price' => SORT_ASC,
            ]),
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 20,
        ],
    ]);
```

А вот где у вас бренд я не могу догадаться.